# How to re-save imported Stata dta file into a CSV file in R Studio

Tags: r, stata

I've imported Stata data set into R by:

```
library(foreign) 
abcdata <- read.dta("abc.dta")
```

How to re-save "abcdata" into a CSV file? Thank you.

Comment: FYI - I down voted your question because you apparently made no effort to find the answer yourself. Any basic Google search for relevant terms would have pointed you towards `write.csv` or `write.table`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
> write.csv(data, file = "fhsdata.csv")
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to read `?write.table`

```
 write.table(data, "abcdata.csv", sep=',')
```

Or directly using:

```
write.csv(...)
```